# rails 4.2 DataTables Cannot reinitialise DataTable

Tags: jquery, ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-4, datatables

I know there are some threads on this and I have been trying different solutions.

I have a very simple 1 page rails 4 app using DataTables gem and when I load the page I get the reinitialize error
"
DataTables warning: table id=pivotal - Cannot reinitialise DataTable. For more information about this error, please see http://datatables.net/tn/3
"

In my Coffee script if I have this line it works fine

```
jQuery ->
  $('#pivotal').dataTable
```

add in a option line and I get the error.  Does not matter what I add.  The table does load just with the popup error.

```
jQuery ->
  $('#pivotal').dataTable
    bJQueryUI: true
    pagingType: "simple"
```

Application JS

```
// Read Sprockets README (https://github.com/sstephenson/sprockets#sprockets-directives) for details
// about supported directives.
//
//= require jquery
//= require jquery_ujs
//= require dataTables/jquery.dataTables
//= require_tree .
```

Application CSS

```
/*
 * This is a manifest file that'll automatically include all the stylesheets available in this directory
 * and any sub-directories. You're free to add application-wide styles to this file and they'll appear at
 * the top of the compiled file, but it's generally better to create a new file per style scope.
 *= require_self
 *= require jquery-ui
 *= require dataTables/src/demo_table_jui
 *= require_tree . 
*/
```

Gem File

```
# Bundle edge Rails instead: gem 'rails', github: 'rails/rails'
gem 'rails', '4.2.0'
# Use sqlite3 as the database for Active Record
gem 'sqlite3'
# Use SCSS for stylesheets
gem 'sass-rails', '~> 5.0'
# Use Uglifier as compressor for JavaScript assets
gem 'uglifier', '>= 1.3.0'
# Use CoffeeScript for .coffee assets and views
gem 'coffee-rails', '~> 4.1.0'

# Use jquery as the JavaScript library
gem 'jquery-rails'
# Turbolinks makes following links in your web application faster. Read more: https://github.com/rails/turbolinks
gem 'turbolinks'
# Build JSON APIs with ease. Read more: https://github.com/rails/jbuilder
gem 'jbuilder', '~> 2.0'
# bundle exec rake doc:rails generates the API under doc/api.
gem 'sdoc', '~> 0.4.0', group: :doc
gem 'tracker_api', '~> 0.2.7'
```

View

```
<table id="pivotal">  
  <thead>
    <tr>
      <th>Story Name</th>
      <th>Story Date Created</th>
    </tr>
  </thead>
 <tbody>
            <% @piv.each do |story| %>

            <tr>
            <td><%= story.name %>  </td>
            <td><%= story.created_at.strftime("%F") %>  </td>
            </tr>

            <% end %>
        </tbody>
</table>
```

Comment: Did you try to add the retrieve: true option?

Comment: Quite possible you have two instances of `jQuery ->
  $('#pivotal').dataTable` in the code.

Comment: I only have 1 coffee script with 1 line in it where would I look for multiple copies of it?

Comment: could you resolve that problem? @ducati1212

Answer (score 1):

You will need to add `bDestroy : true` to the`datatable` option as shown below
jQuery ->

```
$('#pivotal').dataTable
  bJQueryUI: true
  pagingType: "simple"
  bDestroy: true
```